# Adding data to room database skips inside 'for' loop

Tags: database, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, graphql-java

I am facing issue while getting data from response and adding data inside loop sometimes it skips data while adding it to roomDB

//below is code snippet

```
 fun subscribeFeed() {
        try {

            val test =
                apolloClient(mContext!!).subscribe(FeedSubscription(Channel.NORMAL))
            val callback =
                object : ApolloSubscriptionCall.Callback<FeedSubscription.Data> {

                    override fun onResponse(response: com.apollographql.apollo.api.Response<FeedSubscription.Data>) {


                        if (response.data?.Feed?.asMessage?.__typename.equals("Message")) {



                            for (jj in response.data?.Feed?.asMessage?.Ids!!.indices) {

                                try {
                                    val noteDateAdded = Date()
                                    val newNote = ChatAllMsg(
                                        noteDateAdded,
                                        1,
                                        response.data?.Feed?.asMessage!!.text ?: "",
                                        response.data?.Feed?.asMessage?.Ids!![jj],
                                        response.data?.Feed?.asMessage?.type.toString(),
                                        "",
                                        "issent",
                                        response.data?.Feed?.asMessage?.time?.toFloat(),
                                        0,
                                        "",
                                        response.data?.Feed?.asMessage?.Type?.toString()
                                    )

                                    MainScope().launch {
                                        noteDatabase.addMsg(newNote)
                                    }

                                } catch (e: Exception) {
                                    Log.e("catcherror", e.message.toString())

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                  


                }
            test.execute(callback)

        } catch (exception: ApolloException) {
            throw exception
        }


    }
```

inside maincope.launch{} i am adding data to database after getting reponse.

**My main issue is that it skips the data and does not add it to database but i am getting the data in reponse.**
Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Generally you don't want to do things with database in a loop. That opens/closes database for each insert.  Hold the result in a variable and store in in the database as a single insert of a list of all of the data.

Comment: @TheLibrarian i am getting response of id in array form. so to store the id individually i need loop. so after every iteration how will i store the data in database?

Comment: Are there any `catcherror` messages in logs?

Comment: @TheLibrarian no errors

Comment: I didn't mean errors, I meant this exact String 'catcherror'.

Comment: @TheLibrarian no catcherror message in the log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248953/discussion-between-prateek-sharma-and-thelibrarian).